# Difference between previous field in the same column in Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, function

I have a table called `project_errors` which has the columns `project_id`, `total_errors` and `date`. So everyday a batch job runs which inserts a row with the number of errors for a particular project on a given day.

Now I want to know how many errors were reduced and how many errors was introduced for a given month for a project. I thought of a solution of creating trigger after insert which will record if the errors have increased or decreased and put it to another table. But this will not work for previously inserted data. Is there any other way I can do this? I researched about the lag function but not sure how to do this for my problem. The Table structure is given below.

```
Project_Id        Total_Errors       Row_Insert_Date
   1                  56                08-MAR-14 
   2                  14                08-MAR-14
   3                  89                08-MAR-14
   1                  54                07-MAR-14
   2                  7                 07-MAR-14
   3                  80                07-MAR-14
```

And so on...

Comment: What exactly you want to see in the new column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always helpful if you can show the output that you want.  My guess is that you want to subtract 54 from 56 and show that 2 errors were added on project 1, subtract 7 from 14 to show that 7 errors were added on project 2, and subtract 80 from 89 to show that 9 errors were added on project 3.  Assuming that is the case

```
SELECT project_id,
       total_errors,
       lag( total_errors ) over( partition by project_id
                                     order by row_insert_date ) prior_num_errors,
       total_errors -
         lag( total_errors ) over( partition by project_id
                                       order by row_insert_date ) difference
  FROM table_name
```

You may need to throw an `NVL` around the `LAG` if you want the `prior_num_errors` to be 0 on the first day.

Comment: +1 I have the snippets and results, but you are the fast gun.. Can I paste it here?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Justin's answer, you may want to consider changing your table structure.  Instead of recording only totals, you can record the actual errors, then count them.

So suppose you had a table structure like:

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECT_ERRORS(
    project_id INTEGER
    error_id INTEGER
    stamp DATETIME
)
```

Each record would be a separate error (or separate error type), and this would give you more granularity and allow more complex queries.
You could still get your totals by day with:

```
SELECT project_id, COUNT(error_id), TO_CHAR(stamp, 'DD-MON-YY') AS EACH_DAY
FROM PROJECT_ERRORS
GROUP BY project_id, TO_CHAR(stamp, 'DD-MON-YY')
```

And if we combine this with JUSTIN'S AWESOME ANSWER:

```
SELECT 
    project_id                                      AS PROJECT_ID,
    COUNT(error_id)                                 AS TOTAL_ERRORS,
    LAG(COUNT(error_id)) 
            OVER(PARTITION BY project_id
            ORDER BY TO_CHAR(stamp, 'DD-MON-YY'))   AS prior_num_errors,
    COUNT(error_id) - LAG(COUNT(error_id)) 
            OVER(PARTITION BY project_id
            ORDER BY TO_CHAR(stamp, 'DD-MON-YY') )  AS diff
FROM  project_errors
GROUP BY 
    project_id, 
    TO_CHAR(stamp, 'DD-MON-YY')
```

But now you can also get fancy and look for specific types of errors or look during certain times of the day.

Answer (score 0):

Credits to Justin. Just thought of pasting the results.

```
WITH TEMP
     AS (SELECT 1 AS PROJECT_ID,
                56 AS TOTAL_ERRORS,
                '08-MAR-14' AS ROW_INSERT_DATE
         FROM   DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2 AS PROJECT_ID,
                14 AS TOTAL_ERRORS,
                '08-MAR-14' AS ROW_INSERT_DATE
         FROM   DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3 AS PROJECT_ID,
                89 AS TOTAL_ERRORS,
                '08-MAR-14' AS ROW_INSERT_DATE
         FROM   DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1 AS PROJECT_ID,
                54 AS TOTAL_ERRORS,
                '07-MAR-14' AS ROW_INSERT_DATE
         FROM   DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2 AS PROJECT_ID,
                7 AS TOTAL_ERRORS,
                '07-MAR-14' AS ROW_INSERT_DATE
         FROM   DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3 AS PROJECT_ID,
                80 AS TOTAL_ERRORS,
                '07-MAR-14' AS ROW_INSERT_DATE
         FROM   DUAL)
SELECT PROJECT_ID,
       TOTAL_ERRORS,
       NVL (
               TOTAL_ERRORS
             - LAG ( TOTAL_ERRORS )
                  OVER (PARTITION BY PROJECT_ID ORDER BY ROW_INSERT_DATE),
             0 )
          CHANGES,
       ROW_INSERT_DATE
FROM   TEMP;

PROJECT_ID TOTAL_ERRORS    CHANGES ROW_INSERT_DATE
---------- ------------ ---------- ---------------
         1           54          0 07-MAR-14      
         1           56          2 08-MAR-14      
         2            7          0 07-MAR-14      
         2           14          7 08-MAR-14      
         3           80          0 07-MAR-14      
         3           89          9 08-MAR-14      

6 rows selected.
```